# Is it possible to support "rotated" table orientation in react-virtualized?

Tags: react-virtualized

Is there currently a way to "rotate" the orientation of a table? Not dynamically, but just to configure it that way. By "rotate", I mean with headers on the left (in the first "column") and rows displayed to the right (in the second "column" and so on).

From this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No. This is not supported by any built-in components. :)

But you can decorate `Grid` (like `Table` does) and build this type of interface.